# SpringBoot: Why images are not loading html <img src> tag

Tags: spring-boot

As part of my application, I'm saving a dynamically generated list of png files in "/build/test-results/output/png/zpl-1.png". In the html page, I have used all the following:

- `<img src="/zpa/images/zpl-1.png" >`

Works, but my saved images don't store in this location.

- Path: `<img src="/zpa/build/resources/main/static/images/zpl-1.png" >`

Not loading (error 404)

- Absolute path: `<img src="file:///Users/sasi-kathimanda/STS/printing-agent/build/resources/main/static/images/zpl-1.png" >`

Not loading.

---

My configuration:

```
server:
    port: 8090
    contextPath: /zpa
```

Comment: You need to understand the difference between where the images live on the _server_ (a server file path meaningful only on the server) and the URL at which the server makes them available to clients.  These can be wildly different.  The third option works ONLY if your browser is running on the server itself and is generally useless.  In the context of a remote client a `file://` URL points to something on the _client_ machine.

Comment: @JimGarrison: so how can i  tell my <img src> to look for correct location.

Comment: The images anchored at `/build` are in your development environment. During packaging and deployment they will move somewhere else on the server.  We don't know where that will be, or how the server is configured to server them.  Without seeing your server config we can't really help.

Comment: @JimGarrison: ok,i  edit the question to provide server config in the application. please tell me one thing:  what should i change here , avoiding to save images on /build or store it in /tmp instead?  or change the server config ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

although i have tagged this question as "spring boot",probably i was missing it in the title may causes the confusion.

so here is how i solved it, the problem lies in configuring the static web resources in the spring boot config.

```
@Configuration
public class StaticResourceConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {      
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/pngFiles/**")
        .addResourceLocations("file:ext-resources/")
        .setCachePeriod(0);
    }
```

and in my **index.html** using `<img src="/zpa/pnFiles/zpl-1.png">` works.

Comment: WebMvcConfigurerAdapter is deprecated

Answer (score 1):

You can use relative links (with no slash at the beginning) to make the image paths relative to the HTML file that you are including the images in. All three links that you showed are absolute paths.

Relative paths are helpful when you don't know where you are going to be serving the files from, such as when you're just viewing the HTML file instead of actually using a server.

For example, if your HTML file is in the `zpa` folder,

```
<img src="build/resources/main/static/images/zpl-1.png" >
```

Answer (score 1):

Those paths are server file paths and would only work on the local machine (the machine that host the files).

You either need to move the upload directory to somewhere on the public side of the server (ie in the document root) and use a relative path

or

You will need a server side script that can fetch the images from a directory outside the document root and server them as an image.

Comment: well, those paths were not even on working my local machine? i can see the file is stored in /build/test-results/output/png/zpl-1.png but why my dev machine doesn't pick up. probably you are right when hosting in public i need to consider your steps. The reason why i am storing in /build is to store it temporarily and clean when application restarts.

Comment: When you say not working on your local machine, can you access the files directly using those paths?

Comment: If this app is running on a web server and you are accessing it through a browser using http://localhost then those paths still need to be relative to the document root.

Comment: sorry not from browser, i meant to say from the file system. so can you give the eg where i should save from app and how the relative path should look like?

Answer (score 1):

```
**Outside server  call image file using Spring Boot**
  public class StaticResourceConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{
    @Override
        public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

            String filePath = "E:/AshokParmar/Project/imges/";
            registry.addResourceHandler("/img/qrcode/**")
            .addResourceLocations("file:/"+filePath)
            .setCachePeriod(0);
        }
    }
    **in html file use below tags it works**
    <img src="<c:url value="/img/qrcode/0012340012.png" />"/>
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the 
code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score 0):

Dears,

I have followed the below steps to resolve the issue.

**Steps:**
1. My Apache Tomcat 9.0 server installed location is D:\apache-tomcat-9.0.8\apache-tomcat-9.0.8
2. I have created "images" folder under the "webapps" folder in Tomcat installed folder.
Hence my folder structure is "**D:\apache-tomcat-9.0.8\apache-tomcat-9.0.8\webapps\images**".
3. Then I have cleared my browser history and run the application. 
Now images are loading succesufully...